# How do I use Selenium IDE on Firefox to test if a scroll bar is present

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

Please, I am trying to test a website with selenium ide. Now, i need to check if the scroll bar exists or no, if it doesn't exist i want to stop the test. 
Using javascript can we make this test with : `document.getElementById('page').scrollWidth > window.innerWidth`

Answer (score 1):

You need Selenium IDE flow control to do that

```
open      | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random 
storeEval | window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight>window.innerHeight | ${scroll}
gotoIf    | ${scroll} | PASSED
fail_here |
label     | PASSED
```

It is opening a random page of Wikipedia and fails if there is no vertical scrollbar

**UPDATE** Even more simple:

```
verifyEval | window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight>window.innerHeight | true
```